# read yyyy-mm-dd format from XL file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

i had add custom cell style for the XL "yyyy-mm-dd"  and i am read data from XL file in C# application when i read the date column in the data table i can see its in the other format "mm/dd/yyyy"   but i want to validate date format ""yyyy-mm-dd"

```
try
{
    DateTime.ParseExact(dataRow["ServiceDate"].ToString(), "yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //"2014-11-22"
}

catch
{
    //
}
```

but this is not working every time is when to catch statement

but my date in correct format in XL file "yyyy-mm-dd "  how can i fix this   :(

Comment: what is `dataRow["ServiceDate"].ToString()` in your debugger?

Comment: the sequence of `dd/MM/yyyy` depends on your "Culture" settings.

Comment: its show this format mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: well, then .. what are you trying to do with the datetime data? (please be precise)

Comment: i add the data like ""yyyy-mm-dd"" format in XL file and i want to validate that format

Comment: That means, the excel file must not contain a date but a string representation of date... which means you must put `'` before the Excel datetime. If you do it right, you'll see a black arrow on the cell, Top-Left corner

Comment: can u more explain this more in answer box ? it was work thnxz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dataRow["ServiceDate"]).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.TryParse(string, out DateTime)` which will suppress trowing exception on time  validation failure. Pass it in an `if` statement and it will return true, and assign the result to the second argument if the parsing goes OK. Otherwise returns `false`. If validation goes OK use the `ToString(format)` of the date time object to convert it to your preferable format.

```
DateTime formattedTime;

if (!DateTime.TryParse(dataRow["ServiceDate"], out formattedTime)) {
    // dataRow["ServiceDate"] is not a valid date may be throw an exception
}

formattedTime.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd"); // is your formatted time
```

[DateTime.TryParse Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)